# Why does this piece of code freeze everytime?

Tags: c, debugging, crash

```
// program to check if a number is a perfect square or not.
#include<stdio.h>
    
    double perfect_square(double number)
    {
        step:
        for (int i = 1; i<=number; i++)
        {
            if (i*i == number)
            {
                return number;
            }
            else
            {
               goto step;
            }
    
        }
        return 0;
    }
    
    int main ()
    {
        double N;
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%lf", &N);
        double cube_decision = perfect_square(N);
        if (cube_decision == 0)
        {
            printf("It is not a perfect cube");
        }
        else 
        printf("It is a perfect cube."); 
        return 0;
    }
```

The above program lets me input a number but I it just kind of freeze and doesn't do anything onward. I tried replacing **every double variables** with **int variable** and made the function to return **int type** and it worked but my question here is why does this program suddenly freezes when I use double???

- **Note**: This might not be the best program to check perfect square but still it would be of great help if anyone can find the mistake in this program! :)

Comment: Whats the `goto step;` doing? Remove it.

Comment: Today's first lesson should be how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. If you did that you would have found the problem in much less time it took to post this question.

Comment: By the way, perfect *cube*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if the condition `i*i == number` is false, then you start the loop all over again, from the very beginning (with the `int i = 1` part). The `goto` will give you an infinite loop.

You don't nee the `goto` here, the loop will automatically iterate anyway:

```
double perfect_square(double number)
{
    for (int i = 1; i<=number; i++)
    {
        if (i*i == number)
        {
            return number;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And as a general rule, never use `goto` and labels.

Comment: Ah! I got it! Thanks .... actually I am a beginner so I dont have much idea about goto statements....... anyway appreciated :)

Comment: Forget about `goto` statements, @ShubhamBhandari; they are seldom necessary.  They do have uses but those uses are few and far between.